# How to do a batch rendering?

Tags: rust, opengl-es

I have 4 - 5 targets. I draw several triangles for each of them.

```
while !window.should_close() {
    for target in targets.iter() {
        // Update uniform (target.color_value [red, blue, green, yellow] )
        // BindVertexArray
        // DrawElements
    }
}
```

Everything works and my triangles are drawn on the screen in different colors.

Can I have one buffer that I bind once and run the draw command once? Something like

```
while !window.should_close() {
    for target in targets.iter() {
        // Update uniform (target.color_value [red, blue, green, yellow] )
    }
    // BindVertexArray
    // DrawElements
}
```

I tried, but everything is drawn in yellow, as I expected.

I found [How to draw multiple objects by using uniform buffer objects and instanced rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568278/how-to-draw-multiple-objects-by-using-uniform-buffer-objects-and-instanced-rende) as well as `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` and `glDrawArraysInstanced`.

I'm confused about how to organize my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify only one uniform value for all vertexes per draw call.

You can provide additional attribute with color value for each vertex. It'll work the same way how you provide coordinate attribute for triangle vertexes.